# Group and then mutate

Tags: r, mutate

I have a dataset where I want to select only one row for each individual each year - however, I would like to mutate a column so that if it says 'yes' for any of that persons rows then all the rows say 'yes'.

This is an example of the dataset I have:

[image]

So where the name, clinic and year are the same, I want the tested column to say 'yes' if any of the other rows for that grouping say 'yes'.

Therefore, this is what I would want the dataset to finally look like:

[image]

Comment: Hi Vicki Latham, welcome to SO. In future, please do not share images of data for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an minimal, reproducible, example (MRE), and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: I would also suggest instead of `"yes"` and `"no"`, utilise the built in data types of R and use `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: are you wanting it to be grouped by name, clinic,  and year, or just name and year?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward using `dplyr`. Here is an option:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tribble(
  ~ name, ~ clinic, ~ year, ~ date, ~ tested,
  "a",       "xxy",    2022,  "April", "yes",
  "a",       "xxy",    2022,  "May", "no",
  "b",       "ggf",    2019,  "Jan", "no",
  "b",       "ggf",    2019,  "Feb", "yes",
  "c",       "ffr",    2018,  "March", "yes",
  "c",       "ffr",    2019,  "May", "no"
)

df |> 
  mutate(tested2 = if_else(any(tested == "yes"), "yes", "no"), .by = c(name, year))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   name  clinic  year date  tested tested2
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 a     xxy     2022 April yes    yes    
#> 2 a     xxy     2022 May   no     yes    
#> 3 b     ggf     2019 Jan   no     yes    
#> 4 b     ggf     2019 Feb   yes    yes    
#> 5 c     ffr     2018 March yes    yes    
#> 6 c     ffr     2019 May   no     no
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would recommend to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) before posting future questions. It makes easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have included an extra patient who visited two different clinics to demonstrate what happens in those cases as well. This `dplyr` solution works by checking if `any()` values in each `group_by()` are "yes", and then modifies the tested values if true.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = paste0("patient ", rep(c("x", "xy", "xyz", "abc"), each = 2)),
                 clinic = c(rep(c("xxy", "ggf", "ffr"), each = 2), "hhx", "hhy"),
                 year = c(rep(c(2022, 2019), each = 2), 2018, 2019, 2017, 2017),
                 date = month.name[c(4,5,1,2,3,5,6,7)],
                 tested = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no"))

result <- df %>%
  group_by(name, clinic, year) %>%
  mutate(tested = case_when(any(tested == "yes") ~ "yes", TRUE ~ tested)) %>%
  ungroup()


result
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  name        clinic  year date     tested
  <chr>       <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
1 patient x   xxy     2022 April    yes   
2 patient x   xxy     2022 May      yes   
3 patient xy  ggf     2019 January  yes   
4 patient xy  ggf     2019 February yes   
5 patient xyz ffr     2018 March    yes   
6 patient xyz ffr     2019 May      no    
7 patient abc hhx     2017 June     yes   
8 patient abc hhy     2017 July     no
```

Comment: Why are you using `case_when` if you only use two options? Is there some advantage about using `if_else`? You could do `if_else(any(tested == "yes"), "yes", tested))`. BTW, the `TRUE` case in `case_when` is no longer recommended since they added a `.default` argument that do the same.

Comment: @JosepPueyo - hey thanks for the update, most appreciated.